# Run time error 6: Overflow - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Any idea why this is giving me a run time error 6: Overflow?

```
Sheets("Raw data").Select
Dim lastrow2 As Integer
Dim lastcol2 As Integer

lastcol2 = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow2, lastcol2)).Name = "RawData"
```

I've used the exact same vbs code on a different sheet and it runs fine.  All I've done is renamed the variables as lastrow2 and lastcol2.  It's the lastrow2 line that's giving me problems I think.

Comment: Declare as Long not Integer and see if that fixed the problem.

Comment: There is very few advantages using `Integer` type, use `Long` instead.

Comment: I have a similar problem with 
``` m = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("FundedAmounts").Columns(1)) ```

and defining m as a Long instead of a Integer, fixed my problem.